# Absolutely continuous measures perserve under a continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, harmonic-analysis

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function over a compact metric space $X$. Assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two Borel probability measures on $X$.

Suppose that $\mu << \nu$. Is it true that $$f_{\ast}\mu << f_{\ast} \nu?$$
We recall $f_{\ast}\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1} (A)).$

If measures are invariant, then the result is obvious.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(A)$ is a $\nu$-null set, it is also a $\mu$-null set, because $\mu \ll \nu$.